# how to update a parent state most efficiently if its reference state got updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am using Reactjs for my project. if I have states like this:

```
state = {
   child:menuList
   parent1:{
     key1:'some value',
     key2:'some value'
   }
   parent2:{
     key1:'some value',
     key2:'some value'
   }
   parent3:{
     key1:'some value',
     key2:'some value'
   }
}
componentDidMount(){
   const {child} = this.state;
   let {parent1,parent2,parent3} = this.state
   parent1.key3=child;
   parent2.key3=child;
   parent3.key3=child;
   this.setState({
       parent1,
       parent2,
       parent3
   })


}
```

child state is reference of parent1, parent2 and parent3

If I update child state like this: `this.setState({child:menuList2})`, will the parent1, parent2, and parent3 be automatically updated?

If not, what is the most efficient way to update parent1, parent2 and parent3 state if child state got updated

Comment: Is your code compiling properly ? can it reference the child in parent1, when the component is mounting  ?

Comment: @PranayTripathi I am so sorry about the confusion. I am just trying to simplify my code and make it look clearly, but I don't realize that I make a compile error. I have edited it.

Comment: why do you need to complicate the state object here by reassigning to the each parent. I don't think, it's needed if you can tell me otherwise. Any specific requirement here to get served this way ?

Comment: @PranayTripathi In my project, there are about 6 child states that need to be passed to the child component. It might look clearly if we can pack these data and then pass to the child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code given above your `child` state will be assigned to the `parent1`, `parent2` and `parent3` as the `key3` every time your component is mounted. In case the component updates and the child state changes, your parent1, parent2 and parent3 will not have the new state of the child as the component is already mounted.

The best way to solve this complex state problem will be using a state management framework, for example [redux](https://redux.js.org) and split you components in between Presentational and Container Components. You can have a quick read to this [link](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) to understand it in detail.

The other possible way to do it is to extract code in your did mount into another function and you can use `componentDidUpdate` life cycle to update you parent whenever child is not same as previous state. So your code would look something like this:

```
state = {
   child:menuList
   parent1:{
     key1:'some value',
     key2:'some value'
   }
   parent2:{
     key1:'some value',
     key2:'some value'
   }
   parent3:{
     key1:'some value',
     key2:'some value'
   }
}
componentDidMount(){
   this.updateParent();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
    const { child } = this.state;
    const prevChild = prevState.child;
    if(prevChild !== child) {
        this.updateParent();
    }
}

updateParent() {
    const {child} = this.state;
    let {parent1,parent2,parent3} = this.state
    parent1.key3=child;
    parent2.key3=child;
    parent3.key3=child;
    this.setState({
        parent1,
        parent2,
        parent3
    })
}
```

Keep in mind to check the condition in `componentDidUpdate` else your component will go in infinite re rendering loop. If you are using React 16.3.0 or above you can have a look at [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html) and the new lifecycles to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it is really helpful!